# Change NetBeans YAML extension from .yml to .yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, netbeans, yaml

I'm using NetBeans 6.9.1 with the latest PHP plugins, but I'm learning to develop for the Google App Engine. GAE requires an `app.yaml` and doesn't recognize an `app.yml`.

When I instruct NetBeans to create a new YAML file, it does so with a `yml` extension. I want it to be `yaml`.

I've looked at **Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Files** and I find two extensions for YAML: `yml` and `yaml`. I can't find an option to make NetBeans prefer `yaml` over `yml` and I would have liked to remove `yml` altogether but the **Remove** button is greyed out. I also tried tricking NetBeans to thinking that `yml` is associated with `text/xhtml` MIME type, but a **New YAML File...** still results in a `yml` extension.

Comment: Why not just rename the file? You only need one per project, so this isn't going to come up very often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with .html / .htm. I don't have the solution, I'm just creating new **empty file** instead and fill out the extension manually.